# Strategy for combining single page website in larger website

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing a website from scratch using Node and Express with Jade-based templating. The most interactive parts of the website (account mgmt under /user and ordering workflow under /order, both restricted to authenticated users) are based on Angular and almost ready for prime time. I'm now starting work on the less interactive (and non-restricted) parts of the website like the front page, about, faq, support, etc. These less interactive pages will obviously benefit less from using Angular.

I'm trying to get my head around the best strategy for combining these different parts of the website. The options I'm considering are: Angular for the entire website, simple Jade templating with a bit of bespoke JS for the less interactive parts, or everything except the front page in Angular.

My question is: what are the best practices for integrating an Angular (or other single page) website within a larger website? In particular, what are the advantages/disadvantages of the different options I listed above in terms of maintainability, (initial/ongoing) loading speed, consistency for users and search engine optimization? Any options/criteria missing?

Answer (score 0):

For SEO you could use: https://prerender.io/ that should fix that disadvantage

Comment: After doing some reading it looks like this approach is [deprecated](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.hk/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html).